# Creating a default helm chart with custom values

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I created a helm chart using command "helm create sampleapp".

The default chart created by this command has nginx as image.repository, ClusterIP as service.type, autoscaling.maxReplicas as 100 and so on.

Is there a way I can 'create' a default helm chart with my own values by passing them via command line or config? Like image as redis, service.type as NodePort, maxReplicas as 3.

I couldn't find a command line argument to specify the values. The only way seems to be create the default chart and update the values.yaml with what I want. Maybe this is too trivial, but is there a way to do this?

Comment: And helm is supposed to magically know what values are needed? ;) Generate the sample app, then change the values accordingly, test, change again and so on.

Comment: If you know what you want the chart to be already, you might try writing the Kubernetes YAML in the `templates` directory, and hand-writing the `Chart.yaml` and `values.yaml` file, ignoring `helm create`.

Comment: Let's say I know what values I want in the deployment.yaml or service.yaml, but I don't know how the helm chart is structured. What I am looking for is a way to convert my existing yamls into a helm chart. 'helm create' helps with that. But it helps with just the structure, it doesn't allow me to pass the values I know already.